# Is it possible to run an Ubuntu JeOS 9.10 guest in a 9.04 host system?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu Server 9.04 system and building KVM guests of the same version via the vmbuilder script. Now I wonder if it is - in principle - possible to run an newer guest system than the host's system. I tried to upgrade a guest to 9.10 (which is not considered stable, I know) and the guest won't start after reboot.

Does anyone installed an newer guest JeOS than the hosts system? Is it possible? Is it a good thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you shouldn't be able to... KVM is pretty good at virtualisation (especially as it does windows, seamlessly!)

I've got a whole bunch of 9.04 JeOS VMs running inside an 8.04 host..

I suspect if the guest won't boot, it's more likely to be something like grub having been installed badly.  Try adding some kernel switches to the grub config, see if you can get a bit more debug information out about why it won't boot up.

Try booting from a virtual CD image, so you can use it as a boot disk if you have a corrupt MBR on your virtual disk